# Python REGEX search returns None as answer

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm getting None as answer for this code. When I do either email or phone alone the code works. But using both returns a none . Please help!

import re

```
string = 'Love, Kenneth, kenneth+challenge@teamtreehouse.com, 555-555-5555, @kennethlove Chalkley, Andrew, andrew@teamtreehouse.co.uk, 555-555-5556, @chalkers McFarland, Dave, dave.mcfarland@teamtreehouse.com, 555-555-5557, @davemcfarland Kesten, Joy, joy@teamtreehouse.com, 555-555-5558, @joykesten'
contacts = re.search(r'''
    ^(?P<email>[-\w\d.+]+@[-\w\d.]+) # Email
    (?P<phone>\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})$ # Phone
''', string, re.X|re.M)

print(contacts.groupdict)
```

Comment: 1. remove `$`, `^`, 2. Add `,\s*` before `# Email`

Comment: Thanks using this worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
(?P<email>[-\w\d.+]+@[-\w\d.]+), (?P<phone>\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})
```

This matches the parts:

```
kenneth+challenge@teamtreehouse.com, 555-555-5555
andrew@teamtreehouse.co.uk, 555-555-5556
dave.mcfarland@teamtreehouse.com, 555-555-5557
joy@teamtreehouse.com, 555-555-5558
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/TLqHIhi-kVf9ah2B)

Comment: Thanks this works, but I have a task to use re.search and return a groupdict, I messed around a little bit with indentation and using your code worked!. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `^` and `$` to enforce a match on the entire string. Your regexp seems designed to match only a substring.